# Shell script - interactive create user and add to group

Tags: bash, shell

I have a basic script that I wrote that will ask if you want to create a user and then in a separate section will ask if you want to add that new user to the wheel group. I think this could be simplified in one section but it is beyond my ability to get it right. I've tried different ways but I keep failing. Here is the basic script:

```
echo "^^^ Would you like to setup a new user? yes or no: "
read NEWUSERADD
if [ "$NEWUSERADD" == "yes" ]; then
    echo
    echo -n "Enter a username: "
    read NAME
    useradd -m $NAME
    passwd $NAME
else [ "$NEWUSERADD" == "no" ]
    echo
    read -p "**** Not creating a user. Hit [Enter] to continue ****"
fi
# Add new user to wheel group
echo "^^^ Add new user to the wheel group? yes or no: "
read NEWUSERWHEEL
if [ "$NEWUSERWHEEL" == "yes" ]; then
    echo
    usermod -aG wheel $NAME
else [ "$NEWUSERWHEEL" == "no" ]
    echo
    read -p "**** Not adding to wheel group. Hit [Enter} to continue ****"
fi
```

I'm trying to get that second section into the first section to ask, if that user is created, if you would like to add them to wheel group and then if yes to then complete the action.
Is that possible? If so, what would be the best way to do that? I feel it would be another if/else or elif block but I'm not sure how to do that.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `else` shouldn't be followed by a condition. Use `elif` to test a second condition, or `else` to do something when none of the preceding `if` conditions are true.

Comment: This is what you expect? http://pastie.org/p/5zfzD3LBvaYzS5XbqRTSMJ

Comment: @GillesQuénot I think. So you can embed another if/else inside like that?

Comment: @t3kg33k: yes, you are free ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested `if` block to call `useradd` with the `-g wheel` option.

Also, remember to quote all your variables.

```
read -p "^^^ Would you like to setup a new user? yes or no: " NEWUSERADD
if [ "$NEWUSERADD" = "yes" ]; then
    echo
    read -p "Enter a username: " NAME
    read -p "^^^ Add new user to the wheel group? yes or no: " NEWUSERWHEEL
    if [ "$NEWUSERWHEEL" = "yes" ]; then
        useradd -m -g wheel "$NAME"
    else
        useradd -m "$NAME"
    fi
    passwd "$NAME"
else
    echo
    read -p "**** Not creating a user. Hit [Enter] to continue ****"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "^^^ Would you like to setup a new user? yes or no: "
read -r NEWUSERADD
if [ "$NEWUSERADD" == "yes" ]; then
    echo
    echo -n "Enter a username: "
    read -r NAME
    useradd -m "$NAME"
    passwd "$NAME"

    # Add new user to wheel group
    echo "^^^ Add new user to the wheel group? yes or no: "
    read -r NEWUSERWHEEL
    if [ "$NEWUSERWHEEL" == "yes" ]; then
        echo
        usermod -aG wheel "$NAME"
    else [ "$NEWUSERWHEEL" == "no" ]
        echo
        echo "**** Not adding to wheel group. Hit [Enter} to continue ****"
    fi
else [ "$NEWUSERADD" == "no" ]
    echo
    echo  "**** Not creating a user. Hit [Enter] to continue ****"
fi
```